# Select Specific Columns using Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

I browsed various solutions from few days but no one helped me out. I want to fetch

i: userid, username, email (one case)

ii: userid, username, firstname, lastname (second case)

iii: userid, username, password (third case)

and lots of more. I am trying to write a single function to handle all these cases. here is my routine script for fetching records. it fetch all columns which is a set of 40 fields.

```
public static List<vsk_users> FetchRecords(MemberEntity entity)
{
    using (var entities = new vskdbEntities())
    {
         IQueryable<vsk_users> Query = entities.vsk_users
        .Where(p => p.userid == entity.UserID);
         return Query.ToList();
    }
}
```

How to write a select expression that can handle almost any type of column requests instead of writing same function for each custom column selection?

I would use a method like **FetchRecords(--param--)** that can be used to fetch columns which i want/pass through the param object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure it is doable, but you will pay a high price in terms of complexity and performance, since you will have to use **reflection** and build **dynamic** expressions to handle the dynamic nature of your query. You will also have to build the **mapping** of your dynamic results to your vsk_users class items.

If you are not interested in such complexity, a simpler approach could be to use lower-level Entity SQL to build the SQL query string with custom columns, params etc, and then do the mapping to `vsk_users` yourself.

Check out how to execute a parametrized ESQL statement and read data using a data-reader here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738684%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

The mapping should be straight forward, and the performance should be pretty good.

Comment: Thanks yes i think so, there is no direct way to handle it easily. until i use linq.dynamics namespace but this approach is also add complexity and performance impact.